# Installing PG database on ubuntu

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to install PG on my *ubuntu system* but I can't get past this error for `sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.1` :

```
Package postgresql-9.1 is not available, but is referred to by another package. 
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available
from another source
```

or this error for `sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.4` :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package postgresql-9.4
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'postgresql-9.4'
```

or this error for `sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib` :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgresql : Depends: postgresql-9.3 but it is not going to be installed
 postgresql-contrib : Depends: postgresql-contrib-9.3 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is or what I must do to correct it? (I ran `sudo apt-get update` before).

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Try to do a `sudo apt-get update` and see if it helps.

Comment: 14.04. I did say I ran sudo apt-get update :D

Comment: Sorry I did not notice. Can you make a `dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall | grep post` and provide the output?

Comment: libpostproc52     install
postgres-xc     install
postgres-xc-client    install
printer-driver-postscript-hp   install

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have `postgres-xc` installed on your machine, which is a fork of an old version of PostgreSQL that is used for multi-master clustering. The problem is that [Postgres-XC](http://postgres-xc.sourceforge.net/docs/1_1/intro-whatis.html) is **not compatible** with PostgreSQL.

Assuming you need PostgreSQL (and not Postgres-XC), I would suggest that you completely uninstall `postgres-xc` and `postgres-xc-client`, then try to re-install the `postgresql-*` packages again.

Comment: OMG. God is that you ? Thank you so much ! I have been struggling with this for months on many sites(including Stack Overflow). I love you !